# How do I map a dynamic url to a static folder in nginx?

Tags: nginx

As an example

How do you map a url such as /css/(random string here)/test.css

to a static folder:

/css which contains a file in this instance called test.css

updated with non working example:

```
rewrite ^/css/(.*)/$ /css/$1;
```

Comment: Use `rewrite` directive. Have you tried anything?

Comment: thank you I'll try that, I've tried location with various regex and the root / alias directives

Comment: I don't seem to be having much luck with rewrite, I'm a novice with both regex and the nginx dsl, how do I capture the url with my rule and how do I take the filename and apply it to the rewrite?

Comment: edit the question and add your current-non-working configuration. Then we have something to look at

Comment: okay I've added a example I tried earlier I've tried a lot of different variants via trial error - google copy + paste, I don't know whether my rewrite needs to be in a location block or not, and regex is lost on me generally, the most success I've had so far is a redirect loop


also I don't know how to forward the filename from the url to the file path

Answer (score 0):

Your current rewrite rule is capturing the random string. If you want to ignore the random bit this should work:

```
 location /css/ {
          rewrite ^/css/.*/(.*)$ /css/$1;
 }
```

This skips the random string and captures the file name in $1.

Comment: Is there a way to get /css/test.css to resolve too?


It returns a 403 forbidden at the moment, but /css/1.1/test.css resolves perfectly